# Evaluate $\int \frac{z+\overline{z}}{(z-z_0)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z+\overline{z}}{(z-z_0)^2}$$ Where $|z_0|\neq 1$

On the unit circle the integral is:
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{(z-z_0)^2}=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^2+1}{z(z-z_0)^2}$$

Now we have to look at different cases:

1. $|z_0|>1$
2. $|z_0|<1$
3. $z_0=0$

In the case 1:

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^2+1}{z(z-z_0)^2}=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\frac{z^2+1}{z}}{(z-z_0)^2}$$ but $f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z}$ is not analytic at $z=0$ so how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : use the residue theorem with $$f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{z(z-z_0)^2}$$

You will indeed have to discuss the three cases you mentioned.

If $0 < |z_0| < 1$ :
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi i(Res(f,0)+Res(f,z_0))$$
$$Res(f,0) = \lim_{z \to 0}zf(z)=\frac{1}{z_0^2}$$
$$Res(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{(2-1)!}\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}((z-z_0)^2f(z))=\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{z^2-1}{z^2} = \frac{z_0^2-1}{z_0^2}$$
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi i$$

If $z_0 = 0$ :
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi iRes(f,0)$$
$$Res(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{(3-1)!}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^{3-1}}{dz^{3-1}}(z^3f(z))=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z \to z_0}2 =1$$
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi i$$

If $|z_0|>1$
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi iRes(f,0)$$
$$Res(f,0) = \lim_{z \to 0}zf(z)=\frac{1}{z_0^2}$$
$$\oint f(z)dz=2\pi i\frac{1}{z_0^2}$$

Comment: You mean, $$f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{(z-z_0)^2}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did No, On the unit circle the integral is:
$$\oint{\frac{z^2+1}{z(z-z_0)^2}}$$

Comment: The revised version is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of $|z_0|>1$:

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^2+1}{z(z-z_0)^2}dz=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\frac{z^2+1}{(z-z_0)^2}}{z}dz=2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{z_0^2}$$

Using the integrand $$\frac{\frac{z^2+1}{(z-z_0)^2}}{z}$$ the function is analytic at $0$ so we can apply cauchy integral formula

Comment: Which function is "analytic at 0" exactly?

Comment: $\frac{z^2+1}{z-z_o}$

Comment: No, this is not the one one should use. Why are you posting a misleading answer?

Comment: @Did why misleading? I ask my lecturer and this answer is correct

Comment: If your lecturer thinks $$\frac{z^2+1}{z-z_0}$$ is the function to go with, then they are wrong. What is more likely, however, is that they thought you were in fact using $$\frac{z^2+1}{(z-z_0)^2}$$

Comment: @Did yes, sorry I forgot to rise it in power of 2 in the comment, that claim is that we are looking at $\int\frac{f(z)}{z}dz$